# Using sqlalchemy, how can I make a model that sometimes includes relationships and sometimes doesn't?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For example, here is a model I'm using:

```
class IndividualModel(db.Model):
  """
  Individual Model
  """

  # table name
  __tablename__ = 'individual'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  first_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
  middle_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
  last_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
  street_address_1 = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
  street_address_2 = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
  city = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)
  matters = db.relationship('MatterModel', secondary="individual_to_matter", backref='individual', lazy="joined")
```

Is there a way to conditionally tell this class that I actually don't want matters this time?

I tried creating a dupe of this model, which was a weird idea anyway, but SQLAlchemy will only allow one class per table name as far as I can tell.

Comment: You either create the relationship or you don't. It can't be conditional. At runtime you can write queries that retrieve (or do not retrieve) related fields such as this one.

Comment: How would I write a query that doesn't retrieve the related field?  My query looks like this now: IndividualModel.query.all().  What do I add to remove the matters in this query?